# JavaScript last iteration set the value for all iterations

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByName('bb1');
    for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
        var curValue = myElements[i].getAttribute('innerId')
        myElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            alert('Hello i am : ' + curValue);
        }, false);
    }
```

When mouse over, every element, instead of showing a different value for `curValue`, a constant value (the last iteration value) is displayed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no different scope inside blocks like `for` in JavaScript, so when your mouseover event is triggered, it will alert the current variable value which was set in the last iteration.

You can just use `this` inside your callback function to get the attribute of the object which the event was triggered.

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByName('bb1');
for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        alert('Hello i am : ' + this.getAttribute('innerId'));
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general issue here is **the closure in Javascript**. This happens when using variable (in this case **curValue**) not defined within the callback function.

I recommend reading answers about JS closures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).